# Porting MATLAB code from Windows to Mac

Tags: macos, matlab

I have just switched from a PC to a Mac, and I am finding that lots of my MATLAB code previously written when I had a PC does not work on my Mac! I have been working on MATLAB for a while now, but I am not an expert yet.

After searching around for differences between PC and Mac, I noted that a few things indeed differed, but I'd love to hear about whether I need to go through all my yet written MATLAB code and update it manually to make it work on my Mac.

Please let me know what best to do here.

Example:

```
clear all
cd 'c:\users\sss\Desktop\MATLAB\project\DataFile\'
load data
cd ..
```

Why doesn't this work? Is it because of the backslash required for MATLAB on a Mac?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Can you give some example?

Comment: The fact is, I don't know of any code that I wrote on a mac that did NOT work for the pc users I supported when I was doing that. So sorry that you have problems, but this question is not really a question, more of a rant.

Comment: I have been working with matlab on a PC. Now, I have just switch to MAC and transferred all my matlab codes on my MAC. I have tried to launch one of my written function to view a plot, and it does not work.

Comment: I just added an example -

Comment: It is an issue driven by the OS, not MATLAB.

Comment: So - ok - but then what should I do? thanks for the help -

Comment: ALWAYS USE `fullfile` - saves so much troubles!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, if you try to access a Windows-style path on a Mac, it will error.

MATLAB includes a set of functions that make it fairly easy to make your code cross-platform with respect to these sorts of issues. Take a look at, for example, the functions `fullfile`, `fileparts`, `filesep`, `pathsep`, `ispc`, and `ismac`.

I'm afraid that for the moment, you'll probably need to recode things to be either Mac-specific or to be cross-platform using the functions above.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a path variables or variables set which determine where your data is held.  You can even use `computer` or `ismac` and `ispc` to automatically switch to the correct version:

```
if ispc
  dpath = 'c:\users\sss\Desktop\MATLAB\project\DataFile\';
elseif ismac
  dpath = '/Users/sss/MATLAB/project/DataFile/'; 
end
load (fullfile(dpath, 'data.mat'));
```

If you have multiple files in subdirectories of /MATLAB/project/, you can set a project directory (similarly to `matlabroot` but pointing at where your files for that project are kept), and then use `fullfile` to select the correct subdirectory.

e.g. given a directory in proot that points to wherever /MATLAB/project/ is on the appropriate computer, these produce filenames which are in /MATLAB/project/data and MATLAB/project/output respectively:

```
datain = fullfile(proot, 'data','data.mat');
dataout = fullfile(proot,'output','output.mat');
```